# Problema con svg pierde la resolución asignada para la gráfica en amcharts

Tags: javascript, css, html5, css3, amcharts

Esta gráfica funciona de la siguiente manera:

Al hacer clic izquierdo en el equipo **0803029 - Blister (58.97%)** este entrara a un grupo el cual tiene mas items y por lo tanto la gráfica de torta se tiene que reducir para no salir del espacio de **500px** asignados para el **div**, el **svg** al cargar la gráfica al principio obtiene una resolución de **424px**, como ya dije anteriormente al darle clic crea otra lista para la gráfica, esta lista ve obligada a la gráfica de torta a reducir su espacio por lo cual obtiene un poco mas de **256px**, al darle clic derecho retornara a los datos anteriores, por lo cual la gráfica (**svg**) debería de obtener una resolución de **424px**, pero esta sigue con **256px**, por lo cual hace que la gráfica se vea cortada.

```js
let partes = [{"id":2,"nombre":"0803029 - Blister","conteo":23,"padre":0,"partes":[{"id":8,"nombre":"Placas","padre":1,"conteo":3,"partes":[{"id":306,"nombre":"Inferior","padre":8,"conteo":2},{"id":305,"nombre":"Superior ","padre":8,"conteo":2}]},{"id":4,"nombre":"Estación de Calentamiento","padre":2,"conteo":1,"partes":[{"id":7,"nombre":"Placas","padre":4,"conteo":1,"partes":[{"id":9,"nombre":"Placa Superior de Calentamiento","padre":7,"conteo":1},{"id":10,"nombre":"Placa Inferior de Calentamiento","padre":7,"conteo":1}]}]},{"id":341,"nombre":"Sistema de Descarte","padre":2,"conteo":2,"partes":[{"id":342,"nombre":"Dedos de Retension","padre":341,"conteo":2}]},{"id":317,"nombre":"Estación de Corte","padre":2,"conteo":3,"partes":[{"id":320,"nombre":"Ventosas","padre":317,"conteo":3}]},{"id":339,"nombre":"Sistema de Deteccion","padre":2,"conteo":10,"partes":[{"id":340,"nombre":"Camaras","padre":339,"conteo":10}]},{"id":1,"nombre":"Estación de Formación","padre":2,"conteo":4},{"id":334,"nombre":"Sistema de Refrigeracion","padre":2,"conteo":2,"partes":[{"id":338,"nombre":"Condensadora","padre":334,"conteo":1},{"id":335,"nombre":"Compresor","padre":334,"conteo":1},{"id":337,"nombre":"Partes Electricas","padre":334,"conteo":2},{"id":336,"nombre":"Evaporador","padre":334,"conteo":1}]},{"id":309,"nombre":"Estación de Sellado","padre":2,"conteo":5,"partes":[{"id":316,"nombre":"Resortes","padre":309,"conteo":1},{"id":310,"nombre":"Placas","padre":309,"conteo":5,"partes":[{"id":311,"nombre":"Inferior","padre":310,"conteo":5},{"id":312,"nombre":"Superior","padre":310,"conteo":5}]},{"id":313,"nombre":"Esparragos","padre":309,"conteo":1},{"id":314,"nombre":"Muelles","padre":309,"conteo":2},{"id":315,"nombre":"Leva","padre":309,"conteo":1}]}]},{"id":12,"nombre":"0804002 - Llenadora De Liquidos","conteo":16,"padre":0,"partes":[{"id":238,"nombre":"Sistema de Traccion","padre":12,"conteo":2,"partes":[{"id":289,"nombre":"Motor Principal","padre":238,"conteo":2,"partes":[{"id":517,"nombre":"Correa","padre":289,"conteo":2}]}]},{"id":236,"nombre":"Sistema de Llenado de Producto","padre":12,"conteo":13,"partes":[{"id":262,"nombre":"Jeringas de Llenado","padre":236,"conteo":13,"partes":[{"id":266,"nombre":"Sellos","padre":262,"conteo":10},{"id":267,"nombre":"Válvula Sheck","padre":262,"conteo":6},{"id":269,"nombre":"Cuerpo","padre":262,"conteo":3,"partes":[{"id":270,"nombre":"Bocina","padre":269,"conteo":3}]},{"id":265,"nombre":"Rotula Superior","padre":262,"conteo":2},{"id":343,"nombre":"Picos de Llenado","padre":262,"conteo":2},{"id":278,"nombre":"O-Ring","padre":262,"conteo":2},{"id":268,"nombre":"Regleta Dosificadora","padre":262,"conteo":2},{"id":264,"nombre":"Rotula Inferior","padre":262,"conteo":2}]},{"id":261,"nombre":"Estrella Transportadora de Frasco","padre":236,"conteo":1}]},{"id":239,"nombre":"Sistema de Tapado","padre":12,"conteo":3,"partes":[{"id":281,"nombre":"Conjunto Cabezal Magnetico","padre":239,"conteo":2,"partes":[{"id":283,"nombre":"Dado Estriado","padre":281,"conteo":1}]}]}]}];

document.getElementById("chartdiv").oncontextmenu = function(){return false};

var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "pie",
  "language": "es",
  "startDuration": 1,
  "legend":{
    "position":"top",
    "maxColumns":1,
  },
  "responsive": {
    "enabled": true
  },
  "dataProvider": partes,
  "valueField": "conteo",
  "titleField": "nombre",
  "outlineAlpha": 0.4,
  "balloonText": "[[title]]<br><span style='font-size:14px'><b>[[value]]</b> ([[percents]]%)</span>",
  "labelRadius": -35,
  "labelText": "[[percents]]%",
  "disableToggle": true,
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  },
  "listeners": [ 
  {
    "event": "clickSlice",
    "method": function( e ) {
      if(e.event.which == 1){
      if(e.dataItem.dataContext.partes){
          graphic_partes_hijos(e.dataItem.dataContext.id);
        }
      }else if(e.event.which == 2){
      
      }else if(e.event.which == 3){
       if(e.dataItem.dataContext.padre > 0){
            graphic_partes_padre(e.dataItem.dataContext.padre);
        }else{
          chart.dataProvider = [];
          for(n in partes){
            chart.dataProvider.push({
              "id": partes[n].id,
              "nombre": partes[n].nombre,
              "conteo": partes[n].conteo,
              "padre": partes[n].padre,
              "partes": partes[n].partes,
            })
          }
          chart.validateData();
       //chart.animateAgain();
        }
        e.event.preventDefault();
      }
   $( "#chartdiv" ).find( "a" ).hide();
   }
  }],
});

$( "#chartdiv" ).find( "a" ).hide();

let graphics;

function obtener_array_hijos(array, id) {
  for (n in array) {
    if(id === array[n].id){
      graphics = array[n].partes;
      break;
    }else if (array[n].partes) {
      obtener_array_hijos(array[n].partes, id);
    }
  }
}

function graphic_partes_hijos(id){
 graphics = [];
  obtener_array_hijos(partes, id);
  if(graphics !== undefined){
    chart.dataProvider = [];
    graphics.sort(function(b, a){
      let keyA = a.conteo,
          keyB = b.conteo;
      if(keyA < keyB) return -1;
      if(keyA > keyB) return 1;
      return 0;
    });
    for(n in graphics){
      chart.dataProvider.push({
        "id": graphics[n].id,
        "nombre": graphics[n].nombre,
        "conteo": graphics[n].conteo,
        "padre": graphics[n].padre,
        "partes": graphics[n].partes,
      })
    }
    chart.validateData();
    chart.animateAgain();
  }
}

let padre;
function obtener_array_padre(array, id){
  for (n in array) {
    if(id === array[n].id){
   padre = array[n].padre;
      break;
    }else if (array[n].partes) {
      obtener_array_padre(array[n].partes, id);
    }
  }
}
function obtener_array(array){
  for (n in array) {
    if(padre === array[n].id){
      graphics = array[n].partes;
      break;
    }else if (array[n].partes) {
      obtener_array(array[n].partes);
    }
  }
}
function graphic_partes_padre(id){
 graphics = [];
  obtener_array_padre(partes, id);
  if(padre === 0){
    chart.dataProvider = partes;
    chart.validateData();
    chart.animateAgain();
  }else{
    obtener_array(partes);
    if((graphics !== undefined)&&(graphics.length>0)){
      chart.dataProvider = [];
      graphics.sort(function(b, a){
        let keyA = a.conteo,
            keyB = b.conteo;
        if(keyA < keyB) return -1;
        if(keyA > keyB) return 1;
        return 0;
      });
      for(n in graphics){
        chart.dataProvider.push({
          "id": graphics[n].id,
          "nombre": graphics[n].nombre,
          "conteo": graphics[n].conteo,
          "padre": graphics[n].padre,
          "partes": graphics[n].partes,
        })
      }
      chart.validateData();
     chart.animateAgain();
    }else{
      chart.dataProvider = partes;
      chart.validateData();
     chart.animateAgain();
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 11px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  font-size: 11px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/pie.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/amcharts/3.21.6/plugins/export/lang/es.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv" style="height: 500px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

**Explicación gráfica de mi problema:**
[image]

Comment: No es ideal, pero podrías forzar a que el `svg` tenga un alto permanente de 500px y entonces parece que se ve bien siempre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es ideal, pero como solución rápida mientras encuentras la raíz del problema, lo que podrías hacer es con CSS ponerle un alto fijo de 500px a la etiqueta `svg` y forzarlo con `!important` (para que se aplique ese en lugar del estilo en lína de 424px o 256px).

Entonces parece que la gráfica ya se ve bien:

```js
let partes = [{"id":2,"nombre":"0803029 - Blister","conteo":23,"padre":0,"partes":[{"id":8,"nombre":"Placas","padre":1,"conteo":3,"partes":[{"id":306,"nombre":"Inferior","padre":8,"conteo":2},{"id":305,"nombre":"Superior ","padre":8,"conteo":2}]},{"id":4,"nombre":"Estación de Calentamiento","padre":2,"conteo":1,"partes":[{"id":7,"nombre":"Placas","padre":4,"conteo":1,"partes":[{"id":9,"nombre":"Placa Superior de Calentamiento","padre":7,"conteo":1},{"id":10,"nombre":"Placa Inferior de Calentamiento","padre":7,"conteo":1}]}]},{"id":341,"nombre":"Sistema de Descarte","padre":2,"conteo":2,"partes":[{"id":342,"nombre":"Dedos de Retension","padre":341,"conteo":2}]},{"id":317,"nombre":"Estación de Corte","padre":2,"conteo":3,"partes":[{"id":320,"nombre":"Ventosas","padre":317,"conteo":3}]},{"id":339,"nombre":"Sistema de Deteccion","padre":2,"conteo":10,"partes":[{"id":340,"nombre":"Camaras","padre":339,"conteo":10}]},{"id":1,"nombre":"Estación de Formación","padre":2,"conteo":4},{"id":334,"nombre":"Sistema de Refrigeracion","padre":2,"conteo":2,"partes":[{"id":338,"nombre":"Condensadora","padre":334,"conteo":1},{"id":335,"nombre":"Compresor","padre":334,"conteo":1},{"id":337,"nombre":"Partes Electricas","padre":334,"conteo":2},{"id":336,"nombre":"Evaporador","padre":334,"conteo":1}]},{"id":309,"nombre":"Estación de Sellado","padre":2,"conteo":5,"partes":[{"id":316,"nombre":"Resortes","padre":309,"conteo":1},{"id":310,"nombre":"Placas","padre":309,"conteo":5,"partes":[{"id":311,"nombre":"Inferior","padre":310,"conteo":5},{"id":312,"nombre":"Superior","padre":310,"conteo":5}]},{"id":313,"nombre":"Esparragos","padre":309,"conteo":1},{"id":314,"nombre":"Muelles","padre":309,"conteo":2},{"id":315,"nombre":"Leva","padre":309,"conteo":1}]}]},{"id":12,"nombre":"0804002 - Llenadora De Liquidos","conteo":16,"padre":0,"partes":[{"id":238,"nombre":"Sistema de Traccion","padre":12,"conteo":2,"partes":[{"id":289,"nombre":"Motor Principal","padre":238,"conteo":2,"partes":[{"id":517,"nombre":"Correa","padre":289,"conteo":2}]}]},{"id":236,"nombre":"Sistema de Llenado de Producto","padre":12,"conteo":13,"partes":[{"id":262,"nombre":"Jeringas de Llenado","padre":236,"conteo":13,"partes":[{"id":266,"nombre":"Sellos","padre":262,"conteo":10},{"id":267,"nombre":"Válvula Sheck","padre":262,"conteo":6},{"id":269,"nombre":"Cuerpo","padre":262,"conteo":3,"partes":[{"id":270,"nombre":"Bocina","padre":269,"conteo":3}]},{"id":265,"nombre":"Rotula Superior","padre":262,"conteo":2},{"id":343,"nombre":"Picos de Llenado","padre":262,"conteo":2},{"id":278,"nombre":"O-Ring","padre":262,"conteo":2},{"id":268,"nombre":"Regleta Dosificadora","padre":262,"conteo":2},{"id":264,"nombre":"Rotula Inferior","padre":262,"conteo":2}]},{"id":261,"nombre":"Estrella Transportadora de Frasco","padre":236,"conteo":1}]},{"id":239,"nombre":"Sistema de Tapado","padre":12,"conteo":3,"partes":[{"id":281,"nombre":"Conjunto Cabezal Magnetico","padre":239,"conteo":2,"partes":[{"id":283,"nombre":"Dado Estriado","padre":281,"conteo":1}]}]}]}];

document.getElementById("chartdiv").oncontextmenu = function(){return false};

var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "pie",
  "language": "es",
  "startDuration": 1,
  "legend":{
    "position":"top",
    "maxColumns":1,
  },
  "responsive": {
    "enabled": true
  },
  "dataProvider": partes,
  "valueField": "conteo",
  "titleField": "nombre",
  "outlineAlpha": 0.4,
  "balloonText": "[[title]]<br><span style='font-size:14px'><b>[[value]]</b> ([[percents]]%)</span>",
  "labelRadius": -35,
  "labelText": "[[percents]]%",
  "disableToggle": true,
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  },
  "listeners": [ 
  {
    "event": "clickSlice",
    "method": function( e ) {
    
      if(e.event.which == 1){
     
      if(e.dataItem.dataContext.partes){
          graphic_partes_hijos(e.dataItem.dataContext.id);
        }
      }else if(e.event.which == 2){
      
      }else if(e.event.which == 3){
       if(e.dataItem.dataContext.padre > 0){
            graphic_partes_padre(e.dataItem.dataContext.padre);
        }else{
          chart.dataProvider = [];
          for(n in partes){
            chart.dataProvider.push({
              "id": partes[n].id,
              "nombre": partes[n].nombre,
              "conteo": partes[n].conteo,
              "padre": partes[n].padre,
              "partes": partes[n].partes,
            })
          }
          chart.validateData();
       //chart.animateAgain();
        }
        e.event.preventDefault();
      }
   $( "#chartdiv" ).find( "a" ).hide();
   }
  }],
});

$( "#chartdiv" ).find( "a" ).hide();

let graphics;

function obtener_array_hijos(array, id) {
  for (n in array) {
    if(id === array[n].id){
      graphics = array[n].partes;
      break;
    }else if (array[n].partes) {
      obtener_array_hijos(array[n].partes, id);
    }
  }
}

function graphic_partes_hijos(id){
 graphics = [];
  obtener_array_hijos(partes, id);
  if(graphics !== undefined){
    chart.dataProvider = [];
    graphics.sort(function(b, a){
      let keyA = a.conteo,
          keyB = b.conteo;
      if(keyA < keyB) return -1;
      if(keyA > keyB) return 1;
      return 0;
    });
    for(n in graphics){
      chart.dataProvider.push({
        "id": graphics[n].id,
        "nombre": graphics[n].nombre,
        "conteo": graphics[n].conteo,
        "padre": graphics[n].padre,
        "partes": graphics[n].partes,
      })
    }
    chart.validateData();
    chart.animateAgain();
  }
}

let padre;
function obtener_array_padre(array, id){
  for (n in array) {
    if(id === array[n].id){
   padre = array[n].padre;
      break;
    }else if (array[n].partes) {
      obtener_array_padre(array[n].partes, id);
    }
  }
}
function obtener_array(array){
  for (n in array) {
    if(padre === array[n].id){
      graphics = array[n].partes;
      break;
    }else if (array[n].partes) {
      obtener_array(array[n].partes);
    }
  }
}
function graphic_partes_padre(id){
 graphics = [];
  obtener_array_padre(partes, id);
  if(padre === 0){
    chart.dataProvider = partes;
    chart.validateData();
    chart.animateAgain();
  }else{
    obtener_array(partes);
    if((graphics !== undefined)&&(graphics.length>0)){
      chart.dataProvider = [];
      graphics.sort(function(b, a){
        let keyA = a.conteo,
            keyB = b.conteo;
        if(keyA < keyB) return -1;
        if(keyA > keyB) return 1;
        return 0;
      });
      for(n in graphics){
        chart.dataProvider.push({
          "id": graphics[n].id,
          "nombre": graphics[n].nombre,
          "conteo": graphics[n].conteo,
          "padre": graphics[n].padre,
          "partes": graphics[n].partes,
        })
      }
      chart.validateData();
     chart.animateAgain();
    }else{
      chart.dataProvider = partes;
      chart.validateData();
     chart.animateAgain();
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 11px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  font-size: 11px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  float: left;
}

#chartdiv svg {
  height:500px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/pie.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/amcharts/3.21.6/plugins/export/lang/es.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv" style="height: 500px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

Comment: Gracias. Me funciona por el momento, pero como dices no es lo ideal. Espero una respuesta que se relacione con el plugin, si en unos días no veo que alguien responda te apruebo tu respuesta, vale?. Nuevamente, gracias.